# Integrating using Laplace Transforms

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, laplace-transform

$$\int_{0}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2}dt $$

I'm supposed to solve this using Laplace Transformations.

I've been trying this since this morning but I haven't figured it out. Any pointers to push me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?  You mean "calculate"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the integral, and assume temporarily that $x > 0$. This makes no difference since $f(x)$ is even by definition. Then its Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}f(s)$ defines a continuous function on $s \in (0, \infty)$ (in fact, it defines an analytic function on $\Re(s) > 0$). Thus we may assume further that $s \neq 1$ and then rely on the continuity argument. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}f(s)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-sx} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2} e^{-sx} \, dtdx \\
&\stackrel{*}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2} e^{-sx} \, dxdt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+t^2} \frac{s}{s^2+t^2} \, dt \\
&= \frac{s}{1-s^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{s^2+t^2} - \frac{1}{1+t^2} \right) \, dt \\
&= \frac{s}{1-s^2} \frac{\pi}{2} \left( \frac{1}{s} - 1 \right)
= \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{1+s}.
\end{align*}

Here, the change of order of integration $(*)$ is justified by the dominated convergence theorem. Though we proved this for $s \neq 1$, it remains valid by continuity argument as mentioned above. Then by the uniqueness of the Laplace transform, we find that

$$ f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-x}. $$

Therefore we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-\left|x\right|}. $$

Comment: Your answer is derived only for $x \geq 0$, but the integral makes sense for all $x$, so a more complete answer is $(\pi/2)e^{-|x|}$.

Comment: @KCd, Thanks. Of course I knew that, but I forgot mentioning that.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2} \, d\color{red}{t} = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-\left|x\right|}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 5):

Laplace approach :
$$  I= \int\limits_{0}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\left[ \int\limits_{0}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2} e^{-st}\,\mathrm dt \right]_{s=0} =\mathcal{L}\left[ {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2} \right]_{s=0}$$
$$ f(t)=\frac{\cos(xt)}{1+t^2}  $$
$$ (1+t^2)f(t)=\cos(xt) $$
$$ \downarrow\mathcal{L}$$
$$  \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm ds^2}F(s)+F(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+x^2} $$
We have second order differential equation, after we find $ F(s) $
we put zero instead of $ s $.

Where we have used :
$$  \boxed{\mathcal{L} \big\{ t^nf(t)\big\}=(-1)^n \dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm ds^n}F(s)} $$
$$  \boxed{\mathcal{L}\big\{\cos(wt) \big\} = \dfrac{s}{s^2+w^2}} $$

Comment: I don't understand your edit @Brian M. Scott.

Comment: @UnkleRhaukus: The OP’s notation for that step was perfectly acceptable. I consider it inappropriate to make unnecessary changes in someone else’s post, so I restored the original notation. (I was making that change to your edit and restoring the OP’s $d$’s when I discovered that someone had approved the edit while I was working on it.)

Comment: I made those edits because it thought they made the post clearer  more precise, and easier to read.
Do you think restoring that "notation" is necessary or beneficial ?

Comment: The 2nd ODE seems hard to solve.

Answer (score 1):

We can use residue theorm to solve this problem

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} cos(ax) f(x)dx=Real \left[ \oint_{c^+} e^{iaz} f(z)dz \right] = Real \left[ 2\pi i \sum_{i=1}^n R_i^+\right] $$
$$ c^+ : Upper \space half  \space plane \rightarrow uhp $$
$$ c^- : Lower \space half  \space plane \rightarrow lhp $$
$$  R_i^+=Residue(e^{iaz}f(z),z=z_i) \space; \space z_i \space are \space singularities \space in \space c^+  $$
$$ I= \int_{0}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2}dt  $$ 
$$  I=\frac{1}{2}Real \left[ \oint_{c^+} \frac{e^{ixz}}{1+z^2} dz \right] =\frac{1}{2} Real \left[ 2\pi i .R_1 \right] $$
$$  Singularities : 1+z^2=0 \rightarrow   \begin{cases} z_1=i &\mbox{Acceptable (uhp)}   \\
z_2=-i & \mbox{Ineligible (lhp) }  \end{cases} $$

$$  R_1 = Residue(\frac{e^{ixz}}{1+z^2},z=i)=\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \frac{(z-i)e^{ixz}}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{e^{-x}}{2i} $$
so:
$$ I=\frac{1}{2} Real \left[ 2\pi i .R_1 \right]=\frac{1}{2} Real \left[ 2\pi i .\frac{e^{-x}}{2i} \right] =\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's continue the Laplace approach and start from Amir Alizadeh's ...

\begin{align}
I&=\int\limits_{0}^\infty {\cos(xt)\over 1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\
&\stackrel{*}{=}\int\limits_{0}^\infty {\mathcal{L}\left[\cos(xt)\right](\xi)\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left[\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right](\xi)}\,\mathrm d\xi\\
&=\int\limits_{0}^\infty{\frac{\xi}{\xi^2+x^2}\sin\xi}\mathrm d\xi \\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{t\sin(t)}{t^2+x^2}dt\\
&\stackrel{\%}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{|x|\cos(t)}{t^2+x^2}dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-|x|}
\end{align}

where $(*)$ used $\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty(\mathcal{L} f)(s)\cdot(\mathcal{L}^{-1}g)(s)\,ds$ or a good generalization from [Laplace transform of the product of two functions](https://ijpam.uniud.it/online_issue/202044/71%20RamiAlahmad.pdf).

Ps $(\%)$ is just a byproduct when expanding $\sin t=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ and use above formula twice then ended up to the next line which looks like a cousin of the above. Thus from there (and assuming positive $x$ for an even function), one can obtain $I'=-I$ which can be solved by $I=Ce^{-x}$. The constant $C$ is determined by setting $x=0$ in $C=I(x=0)=\int\limits_{0}^\infty {1\over 1+t^2}\,\mathrm dt=\frac\pi2$.