# How to find $f$? (I suppose I need to use the Laplace or the Fourier cosine transform)

Tags: definite-integrals, laplace-transform

$$\int_{0}^\infty{f(x)\cos(xy)\,dx=e^{-y}}$$ 
I try to use Laplace transform for $p=0$. Can I use Fourier cosine transform?

Comment: What's p ?.${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fourier and Laplace are two people: if they were alive, I guess they would like their name to be stated with a capital letter. Besides that, you may use whatever you like, but such identity cannot hold for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$, since the LHS is invariant with respect to $y\mapsto -y$, but the RHS is not.

However:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\color{red}{\frac{\frac{2}{\pi}}{1+x^2}}\,\cos(xy)\,dx = \color{red}{e^{-|y|}}$$
by the properties of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: Is there a method for solving this kind of problem ? ... I had differentiated twice & Integrated by parts & felt like I was getting closer to an answer ... & Is there a smart way to that Integral ?
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(xy)}{1+x^2}dx $

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: to solve the problem it is enough to compute the Fourier cosine transform of $e^{-|y|}$, but to solve a ODE is a viable and effective alternative.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: the integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(xy)}{1+x^2}\,dx $ is straightforward to tackle through the residue theorem.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit you have here that integral https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243800/integrating-using-laplace-transforms

Comment: y in your case is const

Comment: Thanks Jack & FMaster for the answers & leads ... $\ddot \smile$